# How to demodulate a bit sequence that is offset-modulated with a complex exponential?

Tags: filtering, demodulation, peak-detection

I have a discrete-time complex exponential

$a[n]*(\cos(\omega*n/N) + j \sin(\omega*n/N)) + b[n]$

where $a$ is constant and $b$: $\{0,1\}$

So it is basically an offset-modulated sequence of bits and I would like to detect when one of the sinusoids peak, because it is the right time to read out a new value. An easy way to determine when the sine reaches its peak, is by looking at when the cosine is crossing zero from positive to negative values. The problem is that in this case the sinusoid's offset is shifting up and down, as seen in this image

[image: Complex exponential]

My first attempt is to low-pass filter the signal (shown in green) to get something that acts as a zero value would with a sinusoid that is not shifting in offset. This works, but is prone to errors, because sometimes even when given a negative slope, the sample before the crossing is lower than the one after it.

So is there maybe a better way to determine when one of the sinusoids peaks, that doesn't require filtering? I can imagine that you can somehow evaluate this on the complex plane, but due to the shifting offset, I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: What are the three different curves in your graph? Properly labelling your pictures makes it a lot easier to understand them!

Comment: I have added a legend to make it more clear

Comment: Have you tried looking at the zero crossings of the derivative (first difference) instead?

Comment: I am afraid you model is wrong, as it would be close to something like $a_1(k)(sin(2\pi f k)+cos(2\pi fk))+a_2(k)$, so you should be indeed talking about an additive signal, and not about a multiplicative signal. Or perhaps both?. Can you confirm?.

Comment: Oh yeah my formula is wrong. It was supposed to be a plus. I did not take the scalar into account, because I thought it not to be important, but actually it is good to do so.

Comment: @Jdip Yes, that actually works quite well. I haven't considered that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's important to note that the formula you listed is not a complex exponential. I'm not sure if you made a typo, but a complex exponential is:

\begin{equation}a[n][\cos(\omega n/N) + j\sin(\omega n/N)]\end{equation}

However, building off of the formula you listed, there's two ways to approach this. The first is to assume that $a[n]$ is a constant which allows for a simplification that makes calculating when one of the sinusoids peak possible. The second is to assume $a[n]$ is not a constant which leads to a more general form, but has a specific case where a simplification is possible.

Let's assume $a[n]$ is a constant. This means:

\begin{equation}x[n] = a[n][\sin(\omega n/N)+\cos(\omega n/N)] = A[\sin(\omega n/N)+\cos(\omega n/N)]\end{equation}

Taking the derivative we get:

\begin{equation}\dot{x}[n] = \frac{A\omega}{N}[\cos(\omega n/N)+\sin(\omega n/N)]\end{equation}

If we compute $x[n] + \frac{N}{\omega}\dot{x}[n]$ we find that:

\begin{equation}x[n] + \frac{N}{\omega}\dot{x}[n] = 2A\cos(\omega n/N)\end{equation}

This means that if you compute $x[n] + \frac{N}{\omega}\dot{x}[n]$, you get only the cosine portion of the signal. It is also easily shown that for $x[n] - \frac{N}{\omega}\dot{x}[n]$ only the sine wave portion remains. From here, computing the peaks should be fairly easy.

Now, let's assume $a[n]$ is not constant. Taking the derivative we find that:

\begin{equation}\dot{x}[n] = \dot{a}[n][\sin(\omega n/N) + \cos(\omega n/N)] + \frac{\omega}{N}a[n][\cos(\omega n/N) - \sin(\omega n/N)]\end{equation}

If $a[n]$ is known independent of the sine and cosine function, then you can compute $\dot{a}[n]$ and subtract $\dot{a}[n][\sin(\omega n/N) + \cos(\omega n/N)]$ from $\dot{x}[n]$. This leaves you with the first case.

Rearranging in terms of sines and cosines, we get:

\begin{equation}\dot{x}[n] = [\dot{a}[n] - \frac{\omega}{N}a[n]]\sin(\omega n/N) + [\dot{a}[n] + \frac{\omega}{N}a[n]]\cos(\omega n/N)\end{equation}

This highlights a special case of when $a[n]$ is known and is equal to $e^{\alpha n}$ where $\alpha = \pm \frac{\omega}{N}$. In this case one of the terms (depending on if the argument of the exponent is positive or negative) will cancel out. From here, $\dot{x}[n]$ can be combined with $x[n]$ in such a way to produce a purely sine or cosine wave.

For generally unknown $a[n]$ that depends on $n$, there is not an easy analysis via derivatives. There may be another approach that is sufficient for figuring this out, but it is not apparent to me yet.

However, as one other user noted, the graph you posted looks more like your signal is something along the lines of:

\begin{equation}x[n] = A[\sin(\omega n/N) + \cos(\omega n/N)] + b[n]\end{equation}

where $b[n]$ is a time dependent offset, or drift. Taking a derivative of this, we find:

\begin{equation}\dot{x}[n] = \frac{\omega}{N}A[\cos(\omega n/N) - \sin(\omega n/N)] + \dot{b}[n]\end{equation}

If we now calculate $x[n] + \frac{N}{\omega}\dot{x}[n]$, we find that:

\begin{equation}x[n] + \frac{N}{\omega}\dot{x}[n] = 2A\cos(\omega n/N) + b[n] + \frac{N}{\omega}\dot{b}[n]\end{equation}

If you bandpass filter this centered at $\omega$ with a sufficiently narrow filter, you can remove the $b[n] + \frac{N}{\omega}\dot{b}[n]$ term, leaving you with just the cosine. Again, if we instead do $x[n] - \frac{N}{\omega}\dot{x}[n]$ and bandpass filter, we end up with only a sine term. From here, calculating when the peaks occur should be easy.

Comment: Well, they are actually a sine and cosine, which come from different channels. So isolating one of them does not even require calculations.

Looking at the graph though, I thought that you could also treat it as a complex exponential and use some tricks from Euler's formula to extract the data I need.

I mean $sin(\omega n/N) + cos(\omega n/N)$ would be a completely different signal, wouldn't it? Basically a sine modulated with a cosine, which would just be one single sinusoid again https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sin%28x%29+%2B+cos%28x%29

Comment: I filtered the sine with a bandpass filter and took the derivate. I know have a bit error rate of 0.0001 :)

Comment: I see you updated the formula. You’re right that $\sin(\omega n/N) + \cos(\omega n/N)$ is a completely different signal. You get an increased amplitude and a phase shift. The $j$ in $j\sin(\omega n/N)$ essentially acts as a phase shift to the sine wave, making them 90 degrees out of phase. Hope my answer helped!